# Chemfig: submolecules not printing properly after upgrading from TeXLive 2015 to 2020

Tags: tikz-pgf, chemfig, mactex, texlive-2020

Here is a MWE of the code I'm talking about:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\definesubmol{MP}[-[4]P(-[3]O^\ominus)(-[5]O^\ominus)=[4]O]{-P(-[1]O^\ominus)(-[7]O^\ominus)=O}
\definesubmol{MA1}[(-[7])-[4](-[5]O^\ominus)=[3]O]{(-[3])-(-[1]O^\ominus)=[7]O}
\definesubmol{MA2}[(-[1])-[4](-[5]O^\ominus)=[3]O]{(-[5])-(-[1]O^\ominus)=[7]O}
\begin{document}
\chemfig{--[:300]N(-[1]!{MP})-[:330]-[6]-[:210]N(-[7]!{MP})-[:240]-[4]-[:120]N(-[5]!{MP})-[:150]-[2]-[:30]N(-[3]!{MP})-[:60]}
\end{document}
```

After upgrading to TeXLive 2020 (through MacTeX), the submolecules print out the actual string instead of rendering them as structures (see image).

[image]

Before when I had TeXLive 2015, it was printing properly. Does anyone know how to fix this? Thank you!

---

**EDIT:**  A related question with a shorter MWE may be found [HERE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/583246/something-specific-about-my-computer-is-not-rendering-chemfig-submolecules).

Comment: I am running TeX Live 2020, `chemfig` v1.56, and your MWE seems to [compile correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NW1zG.png).

Comment: Also, note that many style guides and recommendations, most importantly, ACS Style Guide, suggest not to place circles around plus or minus signs.

Comment: I am also running the same which is very odd to me. Maybe I will just have to make it a separate figure and import the image

Comment: If you put `\listfiles` before your `\documentclass`, then the log will tell the versions of the files that it uses.  Could you post that as well?

Answer (score 3):

I tried your example with TeX Live 2022/dev and got the following picture:
[image]