# Something specific about my computer is not rendering chemfig submolecules

Tags: chemfig, mactex, texlive-2020

I previously asked [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/569261/chemfig-submolecules-not-printing-properly-after-upgrading-from-texlive-2015-to). When I upgraded from TeXLive 2015 to 2020, submolecules defined using \definesubmol in chemfig would no longer render but simply print out the character sequence (the linked question provides a MWE). Other users, however, said the MWE produced the rendering just fine. In Overleaf, the rendering was also fine. This means there is something specific about my computer and/or TeX distribution.

I am running macOS Catalina with TeXLive provided by MacTeX on an Early 2015 MBP. I don't think there's any hardware or OS-specific issue because like I said everything worked just fine with TeXLive 2015. This means I must have botched something with the upgrade. I uninstalled and reinstalled TeXLive 2020 but the same problem persists.

Does anyone know what it could be? Thank you!

EDIT: More minimal MWE produced below:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\definesubmol{MP}[-[4]P(-[3]O^\ominus)(-[5]O^\ominus)=[4]O]{-P(-[1]O^\ominus)(-[7]O^\ominus)=O}
\begin{document}
\chemfig{!{MP}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you read **"[Updated chemfig gives errors for previously working code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/280692/updated-chemfig-gives-errors-for-previously-working-code)"** -- it seems to be similar.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I did come across that, but it seems like others are able to reproduce the issue in that question, where the answer is actually a difference between TL 2014 and 2015. For my first question (linked in question), others are able to compile my code correctly and only I am having issues. Do you have any thoughts on what that could be?

Comment: You said that you had an MWE, but it looked like you could cut out the {MA1} and {MA2} lines, and I bet you could cut more out if you tried, including most of the submolecule pieces, to produce a better MWE.  The reason why the MWE is so important is because it often leads to a solution, or perhaps a workaround, which may be sufficient for many cases.  The act of making it a truly minimal example helps in the process of elimination -- if it is only one character of the submolecule language causing it, then that may implicate something specific enough to get it fixed or produce a workaround.

Comment: So would you please try to pare down your MWE and make a more minimal MWE?

Comment: @MicroservicesOnDDD thanks for pointing that out. I updated this question with a more minimal example

Comment: Thank you. I will look at it when I get the chance. Does this problem appear only on Mac's? How many people can reproduce this? Thanks.

Comment: Can the "definesubmol{MP}..." line be made shorter in the MWE? Thanks ahead of time.

Answer (score 3):

I just tried your MWE with TeX Live 2022/dev and obtained the following picture.
[image]

Is this what you expected?